# Generating random numbers from the skew-t distribution, problem with density plots

Tags: r, distributions, density-function, random-generation, kernel-smoothing

in another question I was trying to replicate density plots using random numbers coming from the skew-t distribution of Hansen (1994). Now I need to obtain a series of random numbers coming from this distribution. According to the my previous post (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24470/density-plot-of-the-skew-t-distribution) I will use three R packages `sgt`, 'rugarch' and `fGarch`. The vignette of the `sgt` package suggests that by setting the `p = 2` I should obtain the skew-t distribution of Hansen. I conduct a simple experiment to compare my results:

```
require(sgt)
require(fGarch)
require(rugarch)

#skt
x = rsstd(1000000, mean=0, sd=1, nu=30, xi=1+0.5)
y = rsgt(1000000, mu=0, sigma=1, lambda=0.5, p=2, q=30, mean.cent=TRUE, var.adj=TRUE)
z = rdist(distribution = "sstd", 1000000, mu = 0, sigma = 1, skew = 1.5, shape = 30)

plot(density(x), type="l", col="red", main = expression(paste(eta,"=30, ", lambda, "=0.5")), xlim=c(-2, 2))
lines(density(y), col="blue")
lines(density(z), col="green")

x = rsstd(1000000, mean=0, sd=1, nu=3, xi=1+0.5)
y = rsgt(1000000, mu=0, sigma=1, lambda=0.5, p=2, q=3, mean.cent=TRUE, var.adj=TRUE)
z = rdist(distribution = "sstd", 1000000, mu = 0, sigma = 1, skew = 1.5, shape = 3)

plot(density(x), type="l", col="red", main = expression(paste(eta,"=3, ", lambda, "=0.5")), xlim=c(-2, 2))
lines(density(y), col="blue")
lines(density(z), col="green")

x = rsstd(1000000, mean=0, sd=1, nu=2.1, xi=1+0.5)
y = rsgt(1000000, mu=0, sigma=1, lambda=0.5, p=2, q=2.1, mean.cent=TRUE, var.adj=TRUE)
z = rdist(distribution = "sstd", 1000000, mu = 0, sigma = 1, skew = 1.5, shape = 2.1)

plot(density(x), type="l", col="red", main = expression(paste(eta,"=2.1, ", lambda, "=0.5")), xlim=c(-2, 2))
lines(density(y), col="blue")
lines(density(z), col="green")
```

As you can see from running this code that only the first plot is somehow similar, while the others are very much different. I want to generate random numbers using the following parameters $\eta \in (2.1, 3, 30)$ and $\lambda=0.5$. One reason may be that the vignette for the `fGarch` package suggests that the distribution is specified by Fernandez and Steel, not by Hansen, however, in the mentioned post the results seem to be just fine.

Any help on obtaining the correct random numbers from this distribution would be greatly appreciated!

I restrict the values on the x axis to make the plot similar to the one of Hansen (1994).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please include the plots into the question as to avoid readers to re-run your code [and install two packages!]?

Comment: I updated the question with results from yet another package and they still do not match. Any help on this matter would be great.

Comment: Please explain what these plots are trying to show.  They *obviously* are not density plots, because the areas under the red and green curves in the second instance are clearly much larger than the area under the blue curve--and both areas appear to be larger than unity.

Comment: @whuber I am trying to recreate the following plot http://i.stack.imgur.com/QAPk0.png from Hansen (1994). But in general what I ultimately need is a method to draw random numbers from the skew-t distribution of Hansen. And I have troubles finding the correct method to do so. Also in the code you can see that all 3 plots have been generated using the same code as in the first instance, only with different parameters.

Comment: There's some bug in your code, then: by definition (and construction) a density integrates to unity.  Your red and green curves definitely do not have unit area.  At any rate, you would be better off comparing data distributions by means of QQ plots rather than density plots.

Comment: Yep, they should have unit area. But what is puzzling is that for $\eta = 30$ there are no problems and for other values I cannot obtain the desired results. But in general I should be able to obtain three identical plots in each case, right?